# What is the maximum string length I can store in GoInstant?

Tags: goinstant

Rather than deal with a lot of sub-keys I'd like to store a large json structure. Will this cause the world to end?

Answer (score 3):

A string can contain any kind of data, as long as it's less than 32 KB in length.  Which, for your reference, is approximately 16 pages of text!

The official docs have this and more information about Keys: https://developers.goinstant.com/v1/javascript_api/key/index.html